# install theano with python centos-7

Tags: python, centos, theano

I could successfully install theano with python2 by following the instructions here
http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_centos6.html#install-centos6.
Since I do not have root access, I asked my admin to install the additional packages required as mentioned.

sudo yum install python-devel python-nose python-setuptools gcc gcc-gfortran gcc-c++ blas-devel lapack-devel atlas-devel.

This works for python2 but not python3. Are their additional packages required for python3?
Running with python3 gives an error

.theano/compiledir_Linux-3.10-el7.x86_64-x86_64-with-centos-7.2.1511-Core-x86_64-3.4.3-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory.  #include .                     ^. compilation terminated..

Comment: Why doesn't it work on python 3? What do you get as error message ? Could you update your answer to be more detailed ?

Comment: I have added the error I get when executing with python3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you didn't correctly install all the header files and static libraries for python dev. If you have administrative problems you can use Anaconda from `https://www.continuum.io/downloads` 
Else, the most preferred way is using your package manager to install them system-wide.

`sudo yum install python-devel`

Edit : You can install theano with anaconda without admin rights. You can download the anaconda's package for your system, set the appropriate path to the python compiler and then install theano using `conda install theano`. Also, you can install libgpuarray and pygpu, a dependency for using theano's new backend without admin rights, you can find the instructions `http://deeplearning.net/software/libgpuarray/installation.html#step-by-step-install`.

Comment: I do not have admin privileges but had asked my admin to install  these packages                                                                                                   sudo yum install python-devel python-nose python-setuptools gcc
gcc-gfortran gcc-c++ blas-devel lapack-devel atlas-devel.                                         After these were installed I could run theano with python2, but not python3.  I have not used Anaconda before, would I be able to install these required packages with Anaconda without admin rights?

Comment: Yes, you can install with anaconda. I'll update the answer